# Перевести из mysql в Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel5

как правильно записать в laravel такой запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
LEFT join `user_attributes` on user_attributes.user_id = users.id
where 
user_attributes.gender = 2
and user_attributes.city = "Витебск"
and user_attributes.age BETWEEN 18 and 35
        and not exists (select * from likes where likes.like_user = users.id)
LIMIT 4
```

записал так, но что-то не работает

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id','=', 'users.id')
            ->select('user_attributes.user_id','user_attributes.age','user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.fullname','users.id')
            ->where('user_attributes.gender','=', $gender)
            ->where('user_attributes.city','=', Auth::user()->attributes->city)
            ->whereBetween('user_attributes.age', [18, 35])
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('likes')
                    ->whereRaw('likes.like_user != users.id');
            })
            ->inRandomOrder()->take(4)
            ->get();
```

Comment: `not exists (select * from likes where likes.like_user = users.id)` и `exists (select * from likes where likes.like_user != users.id)` - это не одно и то же. Переписывайте на JOIN.

Comment: а как на Join я пробовал, но не выводит ничего

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM `users`
INNER JOIN `user_attributes` ON user_attributes.user_id = users.id
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.like_user = users.id
WHERE user_attributes.gender = 2
  AND user_attributes.city = "Витебск"
  AND user_attributes.age BETWEEN 18 and 35
  AND likes.like_user IS NULL
LIMIT 4
```

и соответственно типа

```
$users = DB::table('users')
->join('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id','=', 'users.id')
->leftJoin('likes', 'likes.like_user', '=', 'users.id')          
->select('user_attributes.user_id','user_attributes.age','user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.fullname','users.id')
->where('user_attributes.gender','=', $gender)
->where('user_attributes.city','=', Auth::user()->attributes->city)
->whereBetween('user_attributes.age', [18, 35])
->whereNULL('likes.like_user')
->inRandomOrder()
->take(4)
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

по вашему замечанию сделал так и все работает

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('user_attributes', 'user_attributes.user_id','=', 'users.id')
            ->select('user_attributes.user_id','user_attributes.age','user_attributes.avatar','user_attributes.fullname','users.id')
            ->where('user_attributes.gender','=', $gender)
            ->where('user_attributes.city','=', Auth::user()->attributes->city)
            ->whereBetween('user_attributes.age', [18, 35])
            ->whereNotExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                    ->from('likes')
                    ->whereRaw('likes.like_user = users.id')
                    ->orWhereRaw('likes.dislike_user = users.id')
                    ->whereRaw('likes.user_id = '.Auth::user()->id.'');
            })
            ->take(4)
            ->get();
```